oncvpsp code usage for pseudo potential generation
Here is the link to the code: oncvpsp
I am trying to modify the LDA norm conserving pp for Ruthenium (an element I have come to despise!). All the newer pp files for it are generated with valence 16 but for my use case they don't work no matter what I do (I can get into more detail but this is not the scope here). The only pp for Ru that worked in the past was an ultrasoft PBE created by Vanderbilt in 2004 I think with a valence of 8. That one works great for what I need, the trouble is it is not LDA.
I am now trying to use the above code to generate an LDA pp for Ru with valence but I cannot figure out how to do it.
I have used the input data for Ru.upf from pseudo-dojo and tried to modify only the valence but I get some errors and the code is not well documented so that I can make sense of what it wants from me.
My question is: can you help me figure out how this code works?

Thank you for contributing your question to our growing site! However, what specifically is your question? This question is likely to get closed with the reason "Needs details and/or clarity", because "how does this code work" is not specific enough.

I will edit the question today. It was late yesterday and I was at my wit's end

Have you read the “user_guide” in the Doc directory ? It explains how the code works. I think the latest version is on GitHub.  https://github.com/oncvpsp/oncvpsp

thank you all! I have managed eventually to convince the code to run and create a new pp. it is such a poorly documented code it is astonishing!
